# Adding elements of a Scala array in pair-wise fashion

Tags: scala

Scala 2.12 here, and new to Scala. I am given an `Array[Double]` which represents the CPU load (%) of all the logical processors on my local system:

```
val logicalProcessorLoads : Array[Double] = cpu.getProcessorCpuLoadBetweenTicks
```

For the sake of this question, the # of logical processors is 2x the number of physical processors or "cores" on the machine.

So on a quad-core machine, there would be 8 logical processors, and so the value of this `logicalProcessorLoads` array at any point in time might be something like:

> [ 12.4, 2.2, 10.0, 5.0, 23.7, 18.9, 1.1, 11.2 ]

So to get the CPU load for all 4 *cores* at any given point in time requires me to iterate through this 8-item array and add each subsequent pair of elements together, hence:

- Core #1 CPU load is 12.4 + 2.2 = 14.6%
- Core #2 CPU load is 10.0 + 5.0 = 15.0%
- Core #3 CPU load is 23.7 + 18.9 = 42.6%
- Core #4 CPU load is 1.1 + 11.2 = 12.3%

etc. I'm trying to find the most concise + clean way of doing this pair-wise addition on my array, with the output being a `perCoreLoads : Array[Double]` with 4-elements in it, each element representing the load for each of my 4 cores. My best attempt so far:

```
var perCoreLoads : Array[Double] = Array()
for((lpl,i) <- logicalProcessorLoads.zipWithIndex) {
  if(i+1 <= logicalProcessorLoads.size - 1) {
    perCoreLoads :+ (lpl(i) + lpl(i+1))
  }
}
```

But this seems a little convoluted and I'm sure Scala's got some magic to help me out here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `grouped` with `map`:

```
logicalProcessorLoads.grouped(2).map(_.sum).toList
```

gives:

```
List(
  14.600000000000001, 
  15.0, 
  42.599999999999994, 
  12.299999999999999
)
```

To understand it better, look at the intermediate result returned by `grouped(2)`:

```
List(
  List(12.4, 2.2), 
  List(10.0, 5.0), 
  List(23.7, 18.9), 
  List(1.1, 11.2)
)
```

those are exactly the summands from the lines in your manually generated table.

Comment: Oh la la, love it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Sliding with Map Approach**

An alternative to @andrey-tyukin answer is to use `sliding` with `map`:

```
logicalProcessorLoads.sliding(2, 2).map(_.sum).toList
```

gives:

```
List(
    14.600000000000001, 
    15.0, 
    42.599999999999994, 
    12.299999999999999
)
```

The intermediate result will also be very similar to grouped, **but `sliding` and `grouped` are quite different**. Sliding will fit this use case as well.

---

**Sliding Approach (slightly descriptive to your example)**:

```
val perCoreLoads = for {
  lpl <- logicalProcessorLoads.sliding(2, 2)
} yield lpl(0) + lpl(1)

println(perCoreLoads.toList)
```

gives:

```
List(
    14.600000000000001, 
    15.0, 
    42.599999999999994, 
    12.299999999999999
)
```

Comment: You `zipWithIndex`, then you pattern-match `i`, then you never use `i`. What's the point of `zipWithIndex` and `i` then?

Comment: Moreover, `grouped` and `sliding` are closely related, it looks like `grouped(n)` could be defined as a special case of `sliding`, namely `sliding(n, n)`.